# list the products by selecting particular " Attribute, Categories, price" in magento

Tags: magento, attributes

visit this link : http://www.firstcry.com/toys-and-gaming?ref2=menu_dd

under "Menu", you can see "Toy finder", below that

"1.child's age", "2.categoty", "3.price" .

we can select the products by selecting above 3 options.

below "Shop by", we can see these options in every site.

how to display these kind of options in products list page or in home page..?...

please help me to find solution.

thanks in advance.

Comment: How you add in 'Home> Toys & Gaming', scriptlets, xml blocks or source code?

Comment: even i also don't have any idea, please give me some ideas....

Answer (score 1):

So first you have to understand how it appears, magento has option to display the path of the blocks etc., as does some research after you know where he is and how he appears, you will have some idea of adding in the home.

One way you can try at home exibilo after learning its operation.

Example:

```
// Create a file in the template folder, and add the filter code.
// In my example I created a page called test in "template/page/html".
// And to display in the home, I used that way    
    <?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setTemplate('page/html/test.phtml')->toHtml();?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('test'); ?> //I used the name of page without extension.
// this way you can add some code in a some page and use somewhere.
```

There are other ways, such as by xml, duplicating or moving the blocks, but before you need to know how it was put out and after that search the best way.

I have helped you in any way.